# How to get the corresponding textview related to a togglebutton in a costum listview?

Tags: android

I have a listview using a costumized ArrayAdapter. I have a textview and a togglebutton inside my list child(single_row.xml). My toggle button is meant to mark/unmark my list items as favorites. In order to update my database (SQLite) I need to access the corresponding textview which is beside the togglebutton.

My problem is that it I don't know how to get the corresponding textview. I am not sure how they are related.

I hope the question is clear.
Thanks

Comment: Access the `TextView` where? In the `OnCheckedChangeListener` for the `Button`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the recommended ways to improve the performance of a listView is using a [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) in the [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method. This ViewHolder object is usually attached to the view using the [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method to be able to retrieve all the views in the row in, for instance, an onClick(View) listener method.

In your case, you could use the same method, but in the ToggleButton, to attach to it an object with the important information of the row. Then, in the [onCheckedChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html), you will receive the ToggleButton that has been pressed, and using the getTag() method you could obtain the previously stored object, with all the information you need to update your database. Something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 //Other stuff here

 ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton)row.findViewById(R.id.toggle_button);

 //Attach to the toggle button whatever object you need
 tb.setTag("Put an object here");
 tb.setOnCheckedChangedListener(new OnCheckedChangedListener(){
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked){
             Object relatedData = button.getTag();
             //Update the database with the relatedData
       }
 });

 //Other stuff

 return row;
}
```